# select text in element while other element is focused

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have problem with selection.addRange and .focus() together.

we have functionality to highlight text in html see img:
http://s23.postimg.org/lbfbhyc8b/screen.jpg

in img you can see I have selected text "investment by nationals", and i want to highlight it, I must click button in header to select color. 
on click i am focusing palette, and starting javascript interval to check his focus and close if it lost focus.

now what is my problem:
in firefox, when i am focusing palette, text selection is losing. this is happening only in firefox. for this problem i saved js range object and make selection again. now in IE appears problem, after manually select range, palette lost focus and interval closed it.

Comment: Could you give us some more explanation ? Maybe a bit of code ?

Comment: The question is more comprehensive now, everything is explained in details. i cant give code because it is split in different files and and objects, i cant collect them all.

Comment: take a look at this, I hope it helps. I don't think addRange works in ie9 below, so you must use createTextRange. I might be wrong. Also, here is the link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536401(v=vs.85).aspx Happy coding.